# echad mi yodea: Aramaic?

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover-seder-hagada, song-poetry, aramaic

A friend of mine told me that the minhag in his family for several generations was to sing "echad mi yodea" in Aramaic. Is there any early source for this?

Comment: Isn't it partially in Aramaic anyway? What were they singing? Chada man yodin, or something like that? (I don't know Aramaic.)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36837 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37639 and sort of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/857

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89692

Comment: I know it’s far in the further, but my family has this minhag too, but it isn’t really a big deal for us, because we speak Aramaic as a conversational language at home, so it would be like singing it in English.

Answer (score 4):

A Google search revealed this [Wikisource entry](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8:%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93_%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A2_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%AA_(%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%9C))

> בעל התפילה, ר' יונתן שטנצל מספר על שיר מיוחד ששמע מסבו הגאון רבי משה
>   הלוי לינשה, זצ"ל נוסח מיוחד עתיק, של אחד מי יודע בארמית שהיו נוהגים
>   לשיר בפסח בחצרות חסידי רוזין, סקווער, סדיגורא, בעיר קישינוב בבסרביה

My translation:

> The chazan Rabbi Jonathan Shtenzel tells of an ancient version of a
>   special song he heard from his grandfather Rabbi Moshe Halevi Lynsha ,
>   ztz”l , אחד מי יודע  in Aramaic which they used to sing on Passover in
>   the chassidic courts of Ruzhin , Skver and Sadigur in the city of
>   Kishinev in Bessarabia.

The entry contains the text – first stanza below:

> חד מה יודא חד מה יודא,? חד חד אנו יודא אנו יודא! טרללללללל...... חד
>   אלוקא, אלוקא, מרן די בשמיא וארעא - מרן די בשמייא וארעא

There is a link to a [Youtube recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItUuaLimkrw), enjoy!

Comment: Cool! But something tells me the spelling might be imprecise.